# reflect changes in devServer without need to reload Node server (Webpack & Vue-cli)

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Let's say I have a Vue CLI project that uses this `vue.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  ...
  devServer: {        
    before: function(app, server, compiler) {
        app.get('/my_response', function(req, res) {                
            res.json({ custom: 'Hello world' });
        });
    },
  }
}
```

To run the server, everytime I use:

```
yarn serve
```

However, once the localhost server is live, and from the front-end, I make AJAX (`axios`, etc) requests to the `/my_response` endpoint, the front-end gets a response, but if i change `"hello world"`, AJAX doesn't get the changed value until `yarn serve` is restarted.

How can I make it so that when I change the backend logic in `vue.config.js`, it wouldn't need a server restart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Vue CLI 4.5.7, there's no built-in support for hot-reloading `vue.config.js`.

A workaround is to install [`npm-watch`](https://github.com/M-Zuber/npm-watch), and edit your `package.json` to include the following:

```js
{
  "watch": {
    "serve": "vue.config.js"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "npm-watch"
  }
}
```